# How to Resize UIView with Subview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

My goal is to resize UIView with a handle - its subview. I got my project working perfectly to accomplish that: the handle has a PanGestureRecognizer and its handler method resizes the view (parent) using the following method:

```
-(IBAction)handleResizeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

  CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:container.superview];
  CGPoint center = container.center;

  switch (recognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        deltaAngle = atan2f(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x) - 
                            CGAffineTransformGetAngle(container.transform);
        initialBounds = container.bounds;
        initialDistance = CGPointGetDistance(center, touchLocation);
        break;
    }

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
        CGFloat scale = CGPointGetDistance(center, touchLocation)/initialDistance;
        CGFloat minimumScale = self.minimumSize/MIN(initialBounds.size.width,   
                                                   initialBounds.size.height);
        scale = MAX(scale, minimumScale);
        CGRect scaledBounds = CGRectScale(initialBounds, scale, scale);
        container.bounds = scaledBounds;

        [container setNeedsDisplay];

        break;
    }

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:

        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Please note that I use **center** and **bounds** properties because frame is **NOT** reliable when transform is applied to my view.

However, my requirement is really to resize the view in ANY direction - not only proportionally as the code does. The problem is that I am not finding the correct methods or approaches how this handle may resize its superview's bounds (width or height) so it always sticks to the corner while finger is dragging it around.

Here is my [project](http://ustymenko.name/idev/DraggableCorner2.zip) if it is easier to see what I mean.

**Updated solution** as suggested by an answer below works very well but once transform is applied (e.g. in viewDidLoad I have `container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);`) it does not:

```
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        initialBounds = container.bounds;
        initialDistance = CGPointGetDistance(center, touchLocation);
        initialDistanceX = CGPointGetDistanceX(center, touchLocation);
        initialDistanceY = CGPointGetDistanceY(center, touchLocation);
        break;
    }

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

        CGFloat scaleX = abs(center.x-touchLocation.x)/initialDistanceX;
        CGFloat scaleY = abs(center.y-touchLocation.y)/initialDistanceY;
        CGFloat minimumScale = self.minimumSize/MIN(initialBounds.size.width, initialBounds.size.height);
        scaleX = MAX(scaleX, minimumScale);
        scaleY = MAX(scaleY, minimumScale);
        CGRect scaledBounds = CGRectScale(initialBounds, scaleX, scaleY);
        container.bounds = scaledBounds;
        [container setNeedsDisplay];

        break;
    }
```

where

```
CG_INLINE CGFloat CGPointGetDistanceX(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2) {
  return (point2.x - point1.x);
}
CG_INLINE CGFloat CGPointGetDistanceY(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2) {
  return (point2.y - point1.y);
}
```

Comment: Why resize with subview? Would be far less complex if you'd wrap both target and handler view into a view. I'd mod the project you've sent if you're ok with that solution.

Comment: Why do you deal with any trigonometry here?

Comment: How else to calculate point distances?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the same scale parameter in your call to CGRectScale(initialBounds, scale, scale); try this:

```
case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGFloat scaleX = abs(center.x-touchLocation.x)/initialDistance;
            CGFloat scaleY = abs(center.y-touchLocation.y)/initialDistance;
            CGFloat minimumScale = self.minimumSize/MIN(initialBounds.size.width, initialBounds.size.height);
            scaleX = MAX(scaleX, minimumScale);
            scaleY = MAX(scaleY, minimumScale);
            CGRect scaledBounds = CGRectScale(initialBounds, scaleX, scaleY);
            container.bounds = scaledBounds;

            [container setNeedsDisplay];

            break;
```

You may also consider to store initialDistanceX and initialDistanceY.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it - this may be very close to what I am looking for.

Comment: It's very close. It jumps on first drag by minimizing the container view but then works as expected. I'll play with it. Thanks.

Comment: Use initialDistanceX and initialDistanceY. That should solve the jump on first drag.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with: CG_INLINE CGFloat CGPointGetDistanceX(CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2){
    return (point2.x - point1.x);} and it seems to be working OK. I will test some more and come back with confirmation.

Comment: One issue: once transform is applied, it does not perfectly work - initialDistanceY seems to be at minimum when view is upside down.

Comment: I started bounty to improve this answer to work with transformed views. Thanks.

Comment: Saikat, your solution is 90% working for me. Any luck on adjusting the code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` & `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Try this code

```
    //--Create and configure the pinch gesture
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGestureDetected:)];
    [pinchGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [container.superview addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];

    //--Create and configure the pan gesture
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureDetected:)];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [container.superview addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

For `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale)];
        [recognizer setScale:1.0];
        panGesture = YES;
    }
}
```

For UIPanGestureRecognizer :

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];
    if (panGesture==YES)
    {
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    }}
}
```

Comment: why pinch recognizer? it seems to complicate it more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not control it with a subview. It gets messy when you apply transform to the outer view.
Simply add two view to the ViewController, and hook them up with some code.
I've altered the project, find [**test-001 at GitHub**](https://github.com/eppz/test-001).

**`ViewController`** code can be empty for this.

The view you want to transform **`TransformableView`** needs a scale property, and a method to apply it (if you want to add other transformations as well).

```
@interface TransformableView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGSize scale;
-(void)applyTransforms;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation TransformableView

-(void)applyTransforms
{
    // Do whatever additional transform you want (e.g. concat additional rotations / mirroring to the transform).
    self.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.scale.width, self.scale.height);
}

@end
```

And the **`DraggableCorner`** can manage the rest (with some basic math).

```
@class TransformableView;
@interface DraggableCorner : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet TransformableView *targetView; // Hook up in IB.
-(IBAction)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) recognizer;

@end
```

---

```
CG_INLINE CGPoint offsetOfPoints(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2)
{ return (CGPoint){point1.x - point2.x, point1.y -point2.y}; }

CG_INLINE CGPoint addPoints(CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2)
{ return (CGPoint){point1.x + point2.x, point1.y + point2.y}; }


@interface DraggableCorner ()
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint touchOffset;
@end


@implementation DraggableCorner


-(IBAction)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    // Location in superview.
    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];

    // Began.
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // Finger distance from handler.
        self.touchOffset = offsetOfPoints(self.center, touchLocation);
    }

    // Moved.
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // Drag.
        self.center = addPoints(touchLocation, self.touchOffset);

        // Desired size.
        CGPoint distanceFromTargetCenter = offsetOfPoints(self.center, self.targetView.center);
        CGSize desiredTargetSize = (CGSize){distanceFromTargetCenter.x * 2.0, distanceFromTargetCenter.y * 2.0};

        // -----
        // You can put limitations here, simply clamp `desiredTargetSize` to some value.
        // -----

        // Scale needed for desired size.
        CGSize targetSize = self.targetView.bounds.size;
        CGSize targetRatio = (CGSize){desiredTargetSize.width / targetSize.width, desiredTargetSize.height / targetSize.height};

        // Apply.
        self.targetView.scale = targetRatio;
        [self.targetView applyTransforms];
    }
}
```

Set the classes in IB, and hook up the `IBAction` and the `IBOutlet` of **`DraggableView`**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but again... The super view must be transformed for me and managing draggable corner is more difficult with this approach.

Comment: I'd wrap these views into an object someting like `ResizableViewGroup`, so you'd won't have the need to "inverse manipulate" the superview. That would stay simple and straight, without freaky backward workarounds.